# Magento 2 - indexer error after data migration magento 1.9.1.1 to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, data-migration, indexer

I'm trying to migrate data to magento 2 using the data migration tool, the migration goes fine but the indexor crash during catalog_product_price index with the error :

```
       SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND dl.store_id = 0
     INNER JOIN `downloadable_link` AS `dll` ON dll.product_id =' at line 2, query was: 
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_temp` SELECT `i`.`entity_id`, `i`.`customer_group_id`, `i`.`website_id`, MIN(IFNULL(dlpw.price_id, dlpd.price)) AS `min_price`, SUM(IFNULL(dlpw.price_id, dlpd.price)) AS `max_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_temp` AS `i`
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `dl` ON dl.entity_id = i.entity_id AND dl.attribute_id =  AND dl.store_id = 0
     INNER JOIN `downloadable_link` AS `dll` ON dll.product_id = i.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `downloadable_link_price` AS `dlpd` ON dll.link_id = dlpd.link_id AND dlpd.website_id = 0
     LEFT JOIN `downloadable_link_price` AS `dlpw` ON dlpd.link_id = dlpw.link_id AND dlpw.website_id = i.website_id WHERE (dl.value = 1) GROUP BY `i`.`entity_id`,
            `i`.`customer_group_id`,
            `i`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`)
```

So, I've got an empty value in the querry :
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `dl` ON dl.entity_id = i.entity_id AND dl.attribute_id =  AND dl.store_id = 0

and that's pretty fun because catalog_product_entity doesn't have a attribut_id column anyway...
So if you've got an idea on how to solve this case i'm ready to listen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems thank the problem come from the data export:

-Two product had no sku, and two had duplicate sku
-one customer attribute and one used in entity attribute where not in eav_attribut table.

It works now after i've corrected those problem.